# Show preloader only once jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with preloader.

I want preloader to be visible only after first visit homepage (or opening url), after that in my case it's still visible by opening new page, refresh website etc...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).load(function() {
    function Preloader() {
        var preloader = $('.preloader');
        preloader.delay (6750) .slideUp(500);
    }
    if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem( 'doNotShow' ) ) {
        sessionStorage.setItem( 'doNotShow', 'true' );
        Preloader();
    } else {
       $ ('.preloader').hide();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

and html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="preloader  preloader-center">
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Makeitmax-logo.svg" alt="">
<p>“uhh.. Hi! We didn’t see you there. One second please”</p>
<button id="preloader-button">Skip</button>
<video autoplay width="896" muted style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;">
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/MakeItMax_Preloader_HD-1-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

website link: [live webite](https://makeitmax.mijnonlinedevelopment.nl/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the preloader simply shows for a short while because your javascript check only runs **after** everything has loaded. This is because you use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).load(function() {
     // check if the cookie exists
});
});
```

By the way, you don't need BOTH those functions.
If you want the preloader to show while the page is loading, just use `$(window).load(..)`.

UPDATE:

Maybe you can check for the cookie right at the start of the document, before anything else. And when the cookie is not there, you add the preloader element.

```
if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem( 'doNotShow' ) ) {
    sessionStorage.setItem( 'doNotShow', 'true' );
    buildPreloader();
}

function buildPreloader() {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("preloader");
    document.body.prepend(div);
}
```

You can add animation using CSS, so you don't have to wait until jQuery is loaded (which would defy the purpose of a preloader)

```
.preloader {
   animation: 3s mycoolanimation;
}
```

More info about animations can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: I placed script before everything, now preloader won't fade at all

Comment: That's because if you can't call `$('.preloader')` before that element is loaded! (and also not before jQuery is loaded). Maybe a solution could be to create a script that ADDS the preloader element when the cookie is not present. Preferably without jQuery, otherwise it won't show when jQuery is still loading.